# npm install issue with "@progress/kendo-angular-grid"

Tags: angular, npm, kendo-ui

I have a project which uses kendo. Below is the package.json file:

**Package.json**-

```
{
  "name": "angular-2-webpack-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A starter kit for angular 2 and webpack",
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "npm run webpack -p --progress --colors",
    "start": "npm run webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --colors",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.19.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^0.10.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^0.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.3.6",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.40",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.0-beta.17",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.2.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^5.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

When I try to run `npm install` for the project I get the below error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not found : @progress/kendo-angular-intl
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@progress/kendo-angular-intl' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'angular-2-webpack-starter'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Is there something that I am missing on installing `@progress` dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you follow steps listed [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/)? Looks like this is paid package so you should request a trial or buy a license.

Comment: Yes I tried with that also. But ` npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress` command I get stuck saying that `Logged in as aakash to scope @progress on https://registry.npm.telerik.com/.` and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

@Aakash, after executing this command:

```
npm login --registry=registry.npm.telerik.com --scope=@progress
```

and entering your credentials, run `npm install` again and it should work fine.